# Si no existe un directorio buscar en otro

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente codigo que busca un archivo en base a un id en un directorio especifico.

Quiero saber como puedo crear una condición de que si el "iframe" no encuentra el archivo en un directorio, lo busque en otro.

```
<?php   
date_default_timezone_set("Chile/Continental");
require_once("../modelo/conexion.php");
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    
    /* Buscar un documento a mostrar */
    $query = $mysqli->query("select d.dir_documentos as dir
                                 from documentos d
                                 where d.id_documentos = '".$id."';");
    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $dir = $row['dir'];
    }
?>
<center>
    <iframe src="../documentos/<?php echo $dir;?>" width="960" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>
</center>
```

Comment: Puedes usar la función [file_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-exists.php) para verificar que el archivo existe.

Comment: Vale gracias me sirvió!

Comment: Puedes responder tú mismo cómo fue que lo solucionaste, pero asegúrate de crear una buena respuesta, con código y explicación de lo que hace. Esto servirá para que usuarios con problemas similares puedan resolverlos.

Answer (score 1):

yo use el file_exist() cuando tenia un problema con los include que variaban con algunas funciones. Pude resolverlo de la siguiente manera:

```
function fileExist(){
    if(file_exists('./consultas/conexion.php')){
        include_once './consultas/conexion.php';
    }else{
        include_once './conexion.php';
    }
}

fileExist();
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos!